# How to Stop Edges from Rounding themselves

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling a car via a tutorial, and for some reason, the mesh is doing this:

[image: Notice how the corners aren't fitting to the vertices]

Notice how the mesh is not touching the tips of angle -- instead bending in. This is happening all over my model. **What have I pressed, and how can I stop it from happening?**
(Currently using Blender 2.79b)

Comment: Seems like you've enabled Subsurf modifier in Edit Mode. Check Modifier tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Looks like you accidentally added a *Subdivision surface* modifier. You can remove it by going to the *Modifiers* tab (the blue wrench) and clicking the `x` button in the upper-right hand corner of the modifier.

[image]

If you don't remember adding the modifier, I'm not surprised -- you probably pressed the keyboard shortcut for it by accident:

From the [Blender Reference Manual](https://easyblend.org/html/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html):

> To quickly add a subsurf modifier to one or more objects, select it/them and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. That will add a subsurf modifier with *View Subdivisions* on 1.
>
> You can use other numbers too, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, etc, to add a subsurf with that number of subdivisions. The *Render Subdivisions* will always be on 2 when added like this.

### Benefits of *Subdivision Surface*

Although it may be annoying now, the *Subdivision surface* modifier generally proves to be one of the most useful tools in any hard-surface modeler's toolkit. Combined with [Loop subdivide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop.html), you can make edges more rounded (and therefore more natural -- nothing is a *perfect* angle in the real world) without all of the shortcomings of the [Bevel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html) modifier.